# Windows Phone 7 Global UI Element?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone, global, mediaelement

I'm trying to add a Global UIElement in my Windows Phone 7 app (ie. a UIElement that is shared across all pages)

Specifically, I'm trying to get the MediaElement to continue playing when I navigate to different pages.

I've tried playing with the Application.RootVisual / PhoneApplicationFrame but I can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a Popup with no parent.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. If you use a Popup -- you'd have to put it within the PhoneApplicationPage right? Meaning if you Navigate away the music would stop playing. Also I can't get the MediaElement to play anything when it's inside a Popup

Comment: You don't have to set the parent of the Popup.

Comment: Works just dandy! Didn't realize what you meant by "no parent" was create it in the code behind and just show it. Was trying to add it from xaml.